# Create item in Sharepoint List with PHP

Tags: list, php

Is it possible to connect to sharepoint and then create an item in a Sharepoint list using php?

Comment: Yes, use SharePoint REST API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Vadim Gremyachev (one of the top helpers here on SO) has created a library

https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

Example 1. How to read SharePoint list items

```
$authCtx = new AuthenticationContext($Url);
$authCtx->acquireTokenForUser($UserName,$Password); //authenticate

$ctx = new ClientContext($Url,$authCtx); //initialize REST client    
$web = $ctx->getWeb();
$list = $web->getLists()->getByTitle($listTitle); //init List resource
$items = $list->getItems();  //prepare a query to retrieve from the 
$ctx->load($items);  //save a query to retrieve list items from the server 
$ctx->executeQuery(); //submit query to SharePoint Online REST service
foreach( $items->getData() as $item ) {
    print "Task: '{$item->Title}'\r\n";
}
```

Example 2. How to create SharePoint list item:

```
$listTitle = 'Tasks';
$list = $ctx->getWeb()->getLists()->getByTitle($listTitle);
$itemProperties = array('Title' => 'Order Approval', 'Body' => 'Order approval task','__metadata' => array('type' => 'SP.Data.TasksListItem'));
$item = $list->addItem($itemProperties);
$ctx->executeQuery();
print "Task '{$item->Title}' has been created.\r\n";
```